# Windows XP Laptop as Access Point using DLink DAP-1350 WiFi Router

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-xp, internet-sharing

I am trying to get my Windows XP Laptop with Telstra 3G internet access to act as the access point for iPad and other devices using a D-Link DAP1350 router (a mini router that I use to turn hotel ethernet into wifi for the same reason).

I have set up ICS on the laptop to share the Telstra connection to the ethernet port on the laptop (192.168.0.1 as per usual ICS settings) and the DAP1350 is set (as default) to 192.168.0.50.

I have the workgroup name set to OFFICE on the laptop (but no way of identifying the workgroup on the ipad or smartphone).

I can see the router from both sides (wireless from ipad and ethernet from laptop) but ipad cannot see the internet.

Any ideas what I might be missing?